# I need to let access only user in .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I need to give only a user the permission to see the web site so this is my htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /party/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /festivalmusicasullacqua/index.php [L]
</IfModule>


AuthBasicProvider file

    AuthUserFile /party/.htpasswd
    AuthName "Authorization Form Title"
    AuthType Basic

    #Allow any valid user
    require valid-user

    #Allow only one user with specified username
    require user festival


    # END WordPress
```

The problem is that when I put the values to log in I get an 500 internal server error. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you use the full path to the password file in the `AuthUserFile` line.

For example, if the file is located in `/var/www/html/party/`, it would be:

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/party/.htpasswd
```